# What weave is the carbon of this carbon wheel?

Tags: road-bike, wheels, carbon

[image]

what weave is this carbon wheel? the brake track and rim are of different weaves? please explain, thanks.

Comment: what kind of a answer are you looking for? are there trades names of different carbon weaves?

Comment: @PaulH Apparently there are quite a lot!  https://www.carbon.ee/en/n/carbon-fiber-all-patterns-explained

Comment: @DavidW there is also the structural and superficial finish carbon layers.  The different finish weaves have  already been covered in  [Difference between UD, 3K and 12K carbon finish?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30962/difference-between-ud-3k-and-12k-carbon-finish)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between UD, 3K and 12K carbon finish?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30962/difference-between-ud-3k-and-12k-carbon-finish)

Comment: Asking the manufacturer would give you the most accurate information.

Answer (score 1):

it is UD pattern,the brake trake are 12k